# Azure pipeline error: MSB3963: Not enough data was provided to generate a launcher. Please provide a value for: 'EntryPoint'

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I have launched this pipeline I hadn't run since May and I'm getting this error when compiling a c# .Net core 3.1 windows forms application that was compiling without problem previously. Using `windows-latest`:

```
[error]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4266,5): Error MSB3963: Not enough data was provided to generate a launcher. Please provide a value for: 'EntryPoint'.
```

I have set the `StartupObject` of the project. Tried to find info on the `EntryPoint` property and `MSB3963` error without sucess. Tried using `windows-2019` image with the same result.

Comment: `MSB3963` is an MSBuild error. It is specific to the `GenerateLauncher` task. The task is not documented in the MSBuild documentation but the source code says it "Generates a bootstrapper for ClickOnce deployment projects." `EntryPoint` is a task parameter.

Comment: @JonathanDodds yes, as far as I can see `EntryPoint` is not being generated and the task fails, but I can't understand why this is happening, as the same code compiled some months ago. I keep searching, thanks for your comment

Comment: In the `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets` file (which is cited in the error message) the `GenerateLauncher` task is used within the `_DeploymentGenerateLauncher` target. That target defines an `ItemGroup` named `EntryPointForLauncher` which is used as the value for the `EntryPoint` parameter. It would seem that none of the conditions for `EntryPointForLauncher` to be defined are being met.

Comment: Hi Mack, maybe you can compare the successful log and the failed log to find if there are any differences, such as software versions, package versions and so on. By the way, to see more detailed logs, you can add a variable named system.debug and set its value to true. If you find something new, please share it here.